# Creating a Data frame that is populated by a custom function that returns an vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following code below and what I would like to do is populate a dataframe.  Each row should be returned from the custom function rX (it returns a vector with 3 numbers).

I've come up with two ways to achieve this but they both feel a bit like work arounds and I was wondering if anyone had a better way to suggest.

Method 1 involves looping through each iteration storing the result in a temporary variable and then putting it in the correct place in the data frame

The second method rbinds the data in but I'm left with blank row which needs to be stripped out after.

```
n=500
ff<-c(0.2,0.3,0.5,0.25)

rX<-function(ff){  
  #generate data frame to hold set selections
  rands<-runif(3)
  s<-rep(0,3)

  for(x in 1:3){
    #generate probabalities from FF
    probs<-cumsum(ff/sum(ff))
    #select first fracture set
    s[x]<-min(which(probs>=rands[x]))
    #get rid of set and recalc
    s[x]
    ff[s[x]]<-0
  }
  rx<-s
}
```

solutions

```
#way 1
df_sets<-data.frame(s1=rep(0,n),s2=rep(0,n),s3=rep(0,n))
for (i in 1:n){
  a<-rX(ff)
  df_sets$s1[i]<-a[1]
  df_sets$s2[i]<-a[2]
  df_sets$s3[i]<-a[3]
}
head(df_sets)

#way 2
df_sets<-data.frame(s1=0,s2=0,s3=0)
for (i in 1:n){
  a<-rX(ff)
  df_sets<-rbind(df_sets,a)
}
df_sets<-df_sets[-1,]
head(df_sets)
```

edit:

The point of this function is to create a number of realizations which select from (without replacement) a predetermined vector which discrete probabilities.  The function rX will use a static input as shown in the function above.  It will select one of the datapoints by comparing a random number between 0 and 1 to the cumulative percent passing at each point.  Then it will remove this point recalculate the probability function and recompare.

Comment: Given your `rX` function, I would do `as.data.frame(t(replicate(10, rX(ff))))`. Provide a more realistic `rX` for a more robust solution. Note that matrices are much faster to work with in R. So don't convert to data frame unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks for that, could you elaborate on providing a more realistic rX?  I will edit the post to reflect what rX is to accomplish

Comment: I used `replicate` since `rX` accepts no inputs. Provide an example of `rX` that takes inputs and also specify how those inputs will be passed to `rX`.